# Using the relation $2(1 – \cos x) < x^2$, $x \ne 0$, prove that $\sin (\tan x) \ge x$ , $x \in [0,\pi/4]$.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

Using the relation $2(1 – \cos x) < x^2$, $x \ne 0$, prove that $\sin (\tan x) \ge x$ ,  $x \in [0,\pi/4]$.

For this problem I tried to use the relation $\tan x > x > \sin x$ for $x \in (0,1)$. Based on this my first step is $(\sin x/2)^2 < (x/2)^2$ , after this step I am struck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to show $\sin(x)\geq \arctan(x)$ over $x\in[0,1]$, or $\cos(x)\geq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, then integrate both sides. Given the hint, that is straightforward:

$$ \forall x\in[0,1],\qquad (1+x^2)\cos(x) \geq \left(1+x^2\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\geq 1\tag{1} $$
hence for any $z\in[0,1]$ we have $\cos(z)\geq \frac{1}{1+z^2}$ and

$$ \forall u\in[0,1],\qquad \sin(u)=\int_{0}^{u}\cos(z)\,dz \geq \int_{0}^{u}\frac{dz}{z^2+1} = \arctan(u) \tag{2}$$
so by setting $u=\tan(x)$ we have:
$$ \forall x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right],\qquad \sin(\tan(x))\geq x.\tag{3} $$